# sqlalchemy+pyodbc for MySQL is giving me an error while trying to create a connection from engine

Tags: python, mysql, pandas, sqlalchemy, pyodbc

I am trying to connect to a MySQL db using sqlalchemy and pyodbc. Connecting using ODBC is a requirement, so I cannot use any other methods for creating engine and connection.
Here the code I am using to create engine and connection.

```
params = quote_plus("DRIVER={MySQL ODBC 8.0 Unicode Driver};"
                                f"SERVER={host}:{port};"
                                f"DATABASE={db};"
                                f"UID={username};"
                                f"PWD={password}")

# Creating dbengine and connection
db_engine = create_engine(f"mysql+pyodbc:///?odbc_connect={params}")
print('Type of dbengine', type(db_engine))
connection = db_engine.connect()
```

I am giving the last 3 lines of the stack trace I am getting from `connection = db_engine.connect()`.

```
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\nice_rpa\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 1276, in _execute_context
    self.dialect.do_execute(
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\nice_rpa\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\default.py", line 608, in do_execute
    cursor.execute(statement, parameters)
TypeError: The first argument to execute must be a string or unicode query.
```

There is no query I am passing or as per the connect() doc, connect takes only 1 kwarg and no query.
I don't understand why I am getting this error. Can someone explain what and why this error?
Also, seems like pyodbc gives a lot of errors sometimes(as per other resources I read). Is there a good alternative for sqlalchemy+pyodbc. I finally want to pass the `connection` to `pd.to_sql` and `pd.read_sql' and using odbc is mandatory.

Comment: what is your type(params) output? is it string? try to write manually into create_engine

Comment: I am unable to reproduce your issue. [This code](https://pastebin.com/gANHN3i2) works fine for me. By chance are you still using Python_2?

Comment: @Gord Thompson I am using python 3.6. I was able to read and write from the same db using username and password. But I need to do it using odbc. You were using urllib.parse.quote_plus right?

Comment: @tyasird It is supposed to be string. I'll give it a try.

Comment: @Jihjohn re: "You were using urllib.parse.quote_plus right?" – Yes.

Comment: @Jihjohn – Also, are you using a reasonably current version of SQLAlchemy?

Comment: @GordThompson yes. I am using sqlalchemy 1.3.23 and pyodbc is 4.0.30

Comment: Ah, okay, I can reproduce the issue with SQLAlchemy 1.3.23. and 1.3.24. It has been fixed in 1.4, but I guess the change didn't get backported to 1.3.

Comment: @GordThompson Thank you so much. Everything is working fine with 1.4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was an issue with SQLAlchemy 1.3.x and `mysql+pyodbc://` that has been fixed in SQLAlchemy 1.4.

Comment: Thank you so much @GordThompson. I wasn't doubting the version of the library at all.

Answer (score 0):

This issue was persistent with SQLAlchemy >1.4.4 I have uninstall Sqlalchemy and install 1.4.0 version which solved the issue

```
pip uninstall SQLAlchemy
pip install SQLAlchemy==1.4.0
```